# Problema com TextBox.Focus(). Repete o SQL ao dar foco no campo

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma função que grava algumas informações em uma tabela ao sair de um `TextBox` (Leave). Porém ao sair, o foco retorna para o primeiro `TextBox`. Quando isso ocorre ele seta o foco como deveria, porém reinsere a linha no banco com as mesmas informações (duplica). O que posso fazer para ajustar?

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
public void InsereDados()
    {
        //Pega o valor dos campos e insere no banco
    }

    public void AtualizaGrid()
    {
        //Atualiza as informações no Grid        
    }

    private void Tbnome_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
            InsereDados();
            AtualizaGrid();
            //Volta o Foco para o Primeiro TextBox
            TbCod.Focus();           

    }
```

Comment: O primeiro `TextBox` tem algum código no evento `Enter` ? Se sim qual ?

Comment: Só no Leave, mas testei dar  o foco em outros que não tem nenhum evento e acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: De alguma forma o evento _Leave_ não está a ser executado duas vezes? Se colocar um _breakpoint_ na 1ª linha do evento, não passa lá uma 2ª vez?

Comment: O `TextBox` deve estar com o `AutoPostBak="true"`

Comment: Troquei o evento Leave por Validating e funcionou. Obrigado a todoso pela ajuda.